# Delphi TWebBrowser print incorrectly applies CSS styling

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

I am using TWebBrowser in Delphi 7, and have a local HTML file, which uses CSS. The CSS has the first line of every new paragraph indented. The problem is, when I print this page (which takes multiple pages of paper), the new paragraph indentation is being applied at the top of every printed page...even though the top of each subsequent page is NOT the beginning of a new paragraph.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var
   vIn, vOut: OleVariant;
begin
   WB.ControlInterface.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, vIn, vOut) ;
```

The relevant CSS code is this:

```
p {
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 20pt;
line-height: 1.75em;
margin-bottom: 1.00em;  
margin-top: 1.00em;
margin-left:1.0em;
margin-right:1.0em; 
text-indent:1.5em;  
}
```

You can see the results below:

[image: Improper formatting]

Should not the text at the top of the page be flush left, rather than indented, seeing how it is not the beginning of a new paragraph?  If I open the same HTML/CSS in Internet Explorer 8, and print it, there is no problem. No indentation occurs at the top of each new page when I use IE8 or Firefox.

A sample HTML file along with the CSS can be found at: http://hostsafe.com/temp/bug.zip

Comment: `TWebBrowser` doesn't incorrectly apply anything. It's merely a wrapper around the Windows `WebBrowser` ActiveX control, and rendering is done by that control. It has nothing to do with Delphi. Also, posting the CSS without the HTML it's being applied to is meaningless when your question has to do with the rendering of that HTML.

Comment: I saw no way to attach files to my question. How do I provide you with the HTML file?

Comment: You add the relevant portions to your question, of course, or post a link to a location it can be found. There's no way to add attachments here (other than graphics.)

Comment: the file you attached does not contain the words you have on the screenshot.